# the code below is supposed to take initial inputs and is supposed to keep on asking for inputs until the both inputs are from 0 to 2000

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, logic, continue

the code below is supposed to take initial inputs and is supposed to keep on asking for inputs until the both inputs are from 0 to 2000 but only asks if both are less than 0 or greater than 2000

```
int main(){

    float x;
    int y;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    scanf("%d",&y);
while(!(x>0 && x<=2000) && !(y>0 && y<=2000)){
    printf("invalid balance or initial amount\n");
    printf("enter initial balance\n");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    printf("enter withdrawal amount\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    continue;
     }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Corner: Is a balance of 0 valid?  I suspect you want `(x>=0 && x<=2000)`

Comment: yes,an error i might have overlooked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: change the middle `&&` to `||`:

```
while (!(x>0 && x<=2000) || !(y>0 && y<=2000)) {
```

Or, you can use an equivalent:

```
while (! ((x>0 && x<=2000) && (y>0 && y<=2000))) {
```

But, I'd clean this up a bit because the *initial* `scanf` calls [before the loop] don't prompt the user. So, I'd reverse the logic a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    float x;
    int y;

    while (1) {
        printf("enter initial balance\n");
        scanf("%f", &x);

        printf("enter withdrawal amount\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);

        if (((x > 0) && (x <= 2000)) && ((y > 0) && (y <= 2000)))
            break;

        printf("invalid balance or initial amount\n");
    }

    printf("x=%g y=%d\n",x,y);

    return 0;
}
```